# Python pip command returning 'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code1'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I keep getting the error "Python pip command returning 'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code1'" when trying to install PyEZ/junos-eznc for some reason. My setuptool and ez-setup are all up to date. Here is a snap of the error:

```
C:\Users\???>py -m pip install junos-eznc
Collecting junos-eznc
  Using cached junos-eznc-1.3.1.tar.gz
Collecting lxml>=3.2.4 (from junos-eznc)
  Using cached lxml-3.6.1.tar.gz
Collecting ncclient>=0.4.6 (from junos-eznc)
  Using cached ncclient-0.5.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\???~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bb5l5lel\ncclient\setup.py", line 32, in <mod
ule>
        long_description = file.read()
      File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line
23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 4336: character maps to <unde
fined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\???~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
build-bb5l5lel\ncclient/
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you run `pip -V` and `python -V`, please?

Comment: Your username in the path looks strange. Does it contain non ASCII characters? I've seen pip failing when the working directory path contained special characters before.

Comment: @Aurora0001 pip 8.1.2, python 3.5.

Comment: @KlausD.I omitted my username from the path, no problems there :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this problem.

Step 1) As Aurora0001 stated, download zip file, delete lines 31 and 32 and replace with:

```
long_description = "Placeholder"
```

then, use pip to install.

Step 2) execute this command:

```
set STATICBUILD=true && pip install lxml
```

Step 3) install junos-eznc using pip

I hope it works for everyone else that has the same problem; and thank you Aurora.

Comment: Glad to hear your problem's solved. Don't forget to accept one of the solutions on this answer (either mine or this one).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is that the description in `ncclient`'s `setup.py` file is being loaded in the wrong encoding. A few other packages seem to have similar issues like the one [here](https://github.com/lxyu/pinyin/issues/9), so I suggest you try this:

- [Download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ncclient) and unzip the latest version directly from PyPI.
- Delete lines [31 and 32](https://github.com/ncclient/ncclient/blob/master/setup.py#L31-L32) from `setup.py`.
- Replace it with the following line:

---

```
long_description = "Placeholder"
```

- Open a command line prompt, `cd` to the directory where you extracted the code and run `py -m pip install .`

It might also be helpful if you file an issue on `ncclient`'s GitHub page - it might help them if you link this thread if this solves the problem.